# Cheerio: Extract Text from HTML with separators

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Let's say I have the following:

```
$ = cheerio.load('<html><body><ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li></body></html>');

var t = $('html').find('*').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.type === 'text';
}).text();
```

I get:

```
OneTwo
```

Instead of:

```
One Two
```

It's the same result I get if I do `$('html').text()`. So basically what I need is to inject a separator like  (space) or `\n`

Notice: This is not a jQuery front-end question is more like NodeJS backend related issue with Cheerio and HTML parsing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
var t = $('html *').contents().map(function() {
    return (this.type === 'text') ? $(this).text() : '';
}).get().join(' ');

console.log(t);
```

Result:

```
One Two
```

Just improved my solution a little bit:

```
var t = $('html *').contents().map(function() {
    return (this.type === 'text') ? $(this).text()+' ' : '';
}).get().join('');
```

Comment: This solution works well until there is inline javascript within a page body, which for some reason it pull in. Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: @tremor I think you could use `.prop("innerText")` instead of `.text()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [TextVersionJS](http://textversionjs.com) package to generate the plain text version of an html string. You can use it on the browser and in node.js as well.

```
var createTextVersion = require("textversionjs");

var yourHtml = "<h1>Your HTML</h1><ul><li>goes</li><li>here.</li></ul>";

var textVersion = createTextVersion(yourHtml);
```

Download it from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/textversionjs) and require it with Browserify for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following function to extract the text from an html separated by a `whitespace` :

```
function extractTextFromHtml(html: string): string {
  const cheerioStatic: CheerioStatic = cheerio.load(html || '');

  return cheerioStatic('html *').contents().toArray()
    .map(element => element.type === 'text' ? cheerioStatic(element).text().trim() : null)
    .filter(text => text)
    .join(' ');
}
```

Comment: ...content().toArray().map(element => {}) .
After applying toArray() to the contents, it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Existing solutions seem a bit vague, selecting `"*"` and using `.contents()` and text node filtering. More straightforward is to directly select the elements we want and map them to their text, then optionally join on spaces:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = "<ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li>";
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const data = $("li").get().map(e => $(e).text().trim()).join(" ");
console.log(data); // => One Two
```